# How can I properly UnMarshal json into a defined struct

Tags: go

I get the error "cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []main.parsed" when I try this

```
package main

import {...}
type parsed struct {
        Title string  `json:"title,string,omitempty"`
}

func Function (args [] String) string {

var jsonData [] parsed
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        if err!= nil {
                return ""
        }        
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &jsonData)
        if err!= nil {
                return ""
        }
    fmt.Println(jsonData)
}
```

Comment: Can you make a sample https://play.golang.org/?
Similar to your's, https://play.golang.org/p/64LCjbg6pI works fine.

Comment: I cannot do http requests in the playground

Comment: Create a `Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example`, `Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem`

Comment: For your case, the varialbe `jsonData ` should have exact structure as `body `. You could use https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/.

Answer (score 0):

> it seems the format is {"id":"value",...} rather than [{"id", "value"}, {}...]

Try replacing

```
var jsonData [] parsed
```

with

```
var jsonData parsed
```